# Javafx resize components when fullscreen

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

**Original size screenshot**

[image]

**Fullscreen screenshot**

[image]

When i resize how can i nicely arrange the components. 
im using FXML for the GUI

FXML CODE

```
    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="style.LoginController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="login" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="242.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="101.0" text="Login" />
      <ImageView fx:id="img2" fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" layoutX="109.0" layoutY="184.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../Downloads/Drawing%20(23).png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label fx:id="title" alignment="CENTER" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="166.0" layoutY="48.0" opacity="0.83" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="269.0" styleClass="title" text="Label" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Narrow" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="txtusername" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="126.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="283.0" promptText="Username" styleClass="fields" />
      <PasswordField fx:id="txtpassword" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="183.0" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="283.0" promptText="Password" styleClass="fields" />
      <ImageView fx:id="img1" fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" layoutX="109.0" layoutY="126.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../Downloads/Drawing%20(22).png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progress" layoutX="197.0" layoutY="120.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="128.0" prefWidth="188.0" progress="0.0" styleClass="progressind" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Can you add the FXML code in the question?

Comment: Please check the FXML code :)

Comment: Do you want the components to be in the just in the middle of the screen when you increase the size of your application or do you want them to stretch in size and increase in size?

Comment: I want them to resize a little and stay middle . Like responsive applications

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is because you are using AnchorPane as your root pane. Though, you can use AnchorPane for scenarios like this, *I personally* do not prefer it because you need to do a lot of things to get it right. There are easier ways to do and that is what I am gonna show you.

From the Javadocs :

> AnchorPane allows the edges of child nodes to be anchored to an offset from the anchor pane's edges.

**Solution**

Use a different layout. May be a [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) or [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html). These layouts have child [alignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#alignmentProperty) instead of anchors, which allow the children to be aligned to a particular position.

For re-sizing your children, you can set the [HGrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) / [VGrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setVgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) property on them.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="20.0" style="-fx-background-color: DARKCYAN;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label text="Easy Doctor" />
      <TextField promptText="Username" />
      <TextField promptText="Password" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="50.0" left="50.0" right="50.0" top="50.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

Here is a small gif on how it looks :

[image]

Comment: this is not working for me.Can somehow the controller doing something to stop resizing?

Comment: This is working for me to width but not to the height of the VBox childrens. How can i affect also the height?

Answer (score 1):

Please add

```
AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"
```

to your image ,button , lable  etc components speciefic size means when screen resize depend on that it will adjust its like Margin in css.

Or

you can add css to align this component as per screen size
like

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
scene.getStylesheets().add(locator.locateAsURL("Css/StudentApp.css").toExternalForm());
scene.getStylesheets().add(("CSS/studentapp.css"));
```