# javafx fullscreen login window controls wont allign properly

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a login page which is full screen,I followed another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095166/javafx-resize-components-when-fullscreen) in stackoverflow and made my login window it looks  perfect with all controls, buttons etc  aligned  to center ,But as soon as I change the screen resolution every thing becomes unaligned . how can I solve this?.I am using scene builder

**fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1360.0" spacing="20.0" styleClass="background" stylesheets="@../UICoreComponents/JMetroDarkTheme.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.MyCompany.attendanceMaster.LoginController">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="278.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="userNameTF" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="248.0" promptText="Username" />
            <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="141.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loginBtnClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="101.0" text="Login" />
            <Button layoutX="145.0" layoutY="141.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clearBtnClicked" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="101.0" text="Clear" />
            <Label layoutX="99.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="62.0" text="Login" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font></Label>
            <PasswordField fx:id="passwordTF" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="248.0" promptText="Password" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets left="550.0" right="550.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

**Main.java**

```
import com.MyCompany.Network.ClientMaster;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;

import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 *
 * @author shersha
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
new StaticController();
     new ClientMaster();

        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();


stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
stage.setFullScreen(true);
 stage.setResizable(false);
        Parent root = StaticController.LOGIN_LOADER.getRoot();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("com/MyCompany/UICoreComponents/JMetroDarkTheme.css");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();



    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**My screen resolution is 1360X768 perfectly alligned**
[image: Screen shot image with out changing my resolution]

**Screen resolution at 1024X768 **
[image]

My final question is how can I make a javafx application that will run screen resolution Independent?(My window size is maximized and not resizable)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is based on a `VBox` and then you are using `padding` to align it. As these values will be the same for all window sizes, it will only work in one case.

Instead you should use a `StackPane` or which centers the content. Into that `StackPane` you add your `Pane`, without any padding. Eventually you need to bind the scene width and heigh to the values of the `StackPane`.

Comment: How to bind scene width and height  I didn't follow ??

Comment: There are at least two ways to do it, take a look at http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/javafx-20-binding/231903245