# JavaFX one component window resize and children auto-resize

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to resize my child components. I'm using VBOX as suggested here: [Javafx resize components when fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095166/javafx-resize-components-when-fullscreen). I am not having any luck with resizing all components according to window width. Only my first panel resizes and I don't know why.

Here is my FXML code :

```
<VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" rotate="-0.0" style="-fx-background-color: ;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="solutions.lunalabs.incubeatthor.scenes.StatusController">
    <children>
        <Pane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #272D2D" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <effect>
                <DropShadow />
            </effect>
            <children>
                <Pane layoutX="159.0" prefWidth="553.0" style="-fx-background-color: #272D2D;">
                    <children>
                        <Label layoutX="146.0" layoutY="14.0" text="STATUS" textFill="WHITE">
                            <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="43.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                        <VBox layoutX="23.0" layoutY="66.0" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="469.0">
                            <children>
                                <Pane fx:id="serverStatus" prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="469.0" style="-fx-background-color: #272D2D;" />
                                <Pane fx:id="generalStatus" prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="469.0" style="-fx-background-color: #272D2D;">
                                    <children>
                                        <VBox prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="469.0" />
                                    </children></Pane>
                                <Pane fx:id="sensorStatus" prefHeight="926.0" prefWidth="469.0" style="-fx-background-color: #272D2D;">
                                    <children>
                                        <VBox prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="489.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Pane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="98.0" prefWidth="549.0" style="-fx-background-color: #36393d;">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <Label layoutX="4.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Temparature" textFill="WHITE">
                                                            <font>
                                                                <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="13.0" />
                                                            </font>
                                                        </Label>
                                                        <Label fx:id="temparatureStatus" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="95.0" text="0C" textFill="WHITE" translateX="3.0">
                                                            <font>
                                                                <Font name="System Bold" size="28.0" />
                                                            </font>
                                                        </Label>
                                                    </children>
                                                    <effect>
                                                        <DropShadow />
                                                    </effect></Pane>
                                            </children>
                                        </VBox>
                                    </children></Pane>
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </children>
                </Pane>
            <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity">
               <children>
                      <Pane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-background-color: #e74c3c;">
                          <children>
                        <VBox>
                           <children>
                                    <Pane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="509.0" prefWidth="52.0" style="-fx-background-color: #34495e;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                        <effect>
                                            <DropShadow />
                                        </effect>
                                    </Pane>
                           </children>
                        </VBox>
                              <JFXButton fx:id="sensorBtn" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="25.0" layoutY="130.0" onAction="#statusHandler" text="SENSORS" textFill="#c5c5c5">
                                  <font>
                                      <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                  </font>
                                  <graphic>
                                      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="HEARTBEAT" size="25.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" />
                                  </graphic>
                              </JFXButton>
                              <JFXButton fx:id="generalBtn" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="25.0" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="77.0" onAction="#statusHandler" text="GENERAL" textFill="#c5c5c5">
                                  <font>
                                      <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                  </font>
                                  <graphic>
                                      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="LEAF" size="25" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" />
                                  </graphic>
                              </JFXButton>
                              <JFXButton fx:id="serverBtn" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="25.0" layoutY="183.0" onAction="#statusHandler" text="SERVER" textFill="#c5c5c5">
                                  <font>
                                      <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                                  </font>
                                  <graphic>
                                      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="TASKS" size="25.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" />
                                  </graphic>
                              </JFXButton>
                              <Label layoutX="54.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="104.0" text="STATUS TAB" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                  <font>
                                      <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="13.0" />
                                  </font>
                              </Label>
                          </children>
                          <effect>
                              <DropShadow />
                          </effect>
                      </Pane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Here is an image of how it looks before resizing:
[image: before window resizing]

And here is an image after resizing the window:
[image: after window resizinh]

I can't seem to figure out how to do the resizing of other child elements not just the first panel child. Also how to resize only vertically and how to resize both? I figure it has to do something with Vgrow but I'm not sure how to implement it. I'm currently using only FXML as I'm playing around with GUI.

Comment: Not sure what the exact desired behavior is, but `VBox` only resizes it;s children and `Pane` simply resizes children to their preferred widths. The outer `Pane` is the only node that gets resized.

Comment: @fabian yea only the outer Pane gets resized. How do I resize other panes? Should I use VBoxes insted of Panes everywhere?

Comment: What kind of behaviour do you expect? Should the size of the "Status Tab" area remain constant horizontally, but grow vertically? The "Status" area including the box beneath should only be resized horizontally, I guess???

Comment: @fabian yes, size of the "Status Tab" should only grow vertically. The area on the right (Status) should be resized both horizontally and vertically, but must not overlay the "Status Tab".

Comment: Why would you leave out the imports?