# Responsive CheckBox JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, responsive-design, responsive

This is my first javaFX project. The project I'm working on includes a feature where the application window can be resized. Upon resizing the window, I expect all objects in my window to increase proportionally according to the window resize. I am not getting this to work with the "CheckBox" Objects.

As you can see below highlighted in red, a CheckBox object is shown before and after a window resize. Before the resize the red checkbox nicely fits  in the green box, but after the resize, the red checkbox is the correct (scaled) width, but did not increase in height as I'd expect. Where should I begin my effort to make my CheckBox objects more vertically responsive?

Minimized
[image: Minimized]
Maximized
[image: Maximized]

As you can see (IN RED), the CheckBox scales horizontally as I expect, but it doesn't scale vertically to occupy the remaining space!

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: It isn't clear what you are expecting.  I also noticed that you have issues with the rounded corners in the top fields - look at the bottom and you will see sharp corners are spilling out below the rounded box.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, how can I clarify my question? I just need to know how to dynamically resize CheckBox objects. For example, If I full screen my window, I'd like my checkBox Objects to increase in size proportionally to the total increase in window size

Comment: read the referenced help page and act accordingly (you can edit your question to add the required example :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javafx resize components when fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095166/javafx-resize-components-when-fullscreen)

Comment: See if some of the ideas from the possible duplicate can help.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more research and helpful responses, I gathered a solution that works.

A "DoubleProperty" object is made, and binded to the width of the container holding my checkboxes. Call this container, "dryLeafGridPane" for example.

```
DoubleProperty checkboxFontSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10);
checkboxFontSize.bind((dryLeafGridPane.widthProperty().divide(36)));
```

The .divide(36) scales the CheckBox's font size to 1/36 the gridpane's width.
Finally, I just add the new font size using CSS.

```
dryLeafGridPane.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("-fx-font-size: ", checkboxFontSize.asString()));
```

Here is a [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/032oc.gif) of the (slightly more) responsive app!

Comment: sorry, is this better?

Comment: yeah, thanks :) A little nitpick: you might consider to format the code as a block (leading 4 spaces) vs. inline

Answer (score -1):

You can choose to increase the font size on the root pane when you go full screen.  For example:

```
rootPane.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 150%;");
```

That isn't perfect though... it seems the size of the box that is checked doesn't scale with the font.